# Increasing queue size when traversing by level order

Tags: java, queue, binary-search-tree, traversal

I am traversing through a BST using a level order class. When I add an element to my queue class I need the size of the queue to increase, but as my code is right now it isn't:

```
public class LevelorderIterator implements Iterator<Node> {
protected Queue<Node> q;
Node root;
public LevelorderIterator(Node tree) {
    this.root = tree;
    q = new Queue <Node>();
    q.enqueue(root);
}

public Node next() {
    Node temp = q.dequeue();
    if(temp.left != null){
        q.enqueue(temp.left);
    }
    if(temp.right != null){
        q.enqueue(temp.right);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Enqueue (in queue class):

```
public void enqueue(E item) {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        lst = fst = new QueueItem<E>(item, null);
    } else {
        lst.next = new QueueItem<E>(item, null);
        lst = lst.next;
    }
    size++;
}
```

The traversing works fine so I'm guessing I've become blinded from starring at my code for too long... Where am I looking at this the wrong way?

Edit:
This is my dequeue:

```
  public E dequeue() throws EmptyContainerException {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new EmptyContainerException(">>> Queue is empty.");
    }
    E e = fst.element;
    fst = fst.next;
    size--;
    if (isEmpty()) {
        lst = null;
    }
    return e;
}
```

In my testprogram I call next, which then calls dequeue:

```
case 'l':
LevelorderIterator lo = tree.levelorder();
while (lo.hasNext()) {
    Node tmp = lo.next();
    System.out.println("Key=" + tmp.key + " Value="
            + tmp.val);
}
```

So after this case I get an output of nodes in BST in correct order. But if I check the size of my queue it is always '1', even when my BST is for example 5. The size 1 comes from the enqueue in the constructor of lo. What I want is for my queue size to be the same as BST until I start dequeueing it or deleteing elements from the BST.

Thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why are you rolling your own queue class instead of using `java.util.Queue` along with one of its implementations (e.g. `LinkedList`)? Besides that your `enqueue()` method looks ok, did you step through your code with a debugger? (That's preferrable over staring at code :) )

Comment: I am simply trying to learn better how ADTs works :) I'm not sure what a debugger is, but I don't get any errors really, the problem is that I don't get the results I'm looking for (having the same size in my queue as in my BST). @Thomas

Comment: This code looks pretty reasonable to me--can you post a more complete (but still [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) example that shows the problem exactly?

Comment: @ggorlen I edited my post. New info is under "edit: ".

Comment: A debugger is used to step through your program (statement by statement, from defined break point to break point etc.) to see what code is called and what values the parameters, variables or fields have. It's _really_ helpful, especially in cases like yours, i.e. when there's no exception or warning but the code still does something wrong somewhere (stepping though the code and looking at the values is meant to help you find what goes wrong and where).

Comment: As for your problem: " What I want is for my queue size to be the same as BST until I start dequeueing it or deleteing elements from the BST." - have a look at your iterator's `next()` method: you're calling `dequeue()` there so your queue should be empty (not sure where that 1 comes from) after iteration. However, since the queue is meant for iteration why exactly do you want its size to be equal to that of the tree?